# Question about the fundamental group of rational homology 3-spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 3-manifolds, fundamental-group

By a rational homology 3-sphere, I mean a compact oriented manifold three-manifold $Y$ with $H_1(Y)$ finite. My question is whether there exists a reasonable classification of such manifolds such that $\pi_1(Y)$ has a minimal presentation with two generators? How about three generators?

Here are the examples I know:

Example 1. Connected sum of lens spaces
Example 2. Poincare sphere (Thanks to Qiaochu Yuan for pointing out in a previous version of this question that the Poincare sphere satisfies these criteria).

Comment: Well, there are other spherical 3-manifolds besides lens spaces and the Poincare dodecahedral sphere (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_3-manifold), although I'm not sure which ones you get by taking connected sums of lens spaces. The prism manifolds admit a presentation with two generators.

Comment: Two families: any nonzero rational surgery on a 2-bridge knot; any rational homology sphere with an open book with genus 1 and 1 boundary component (e.g. branched covers of the trefoil and the figure 8). These are special cases of rational homology spheres that admit a genus-2 Heegaard diagram.

Comment: I do not know if that helps, but here is a remark. Assume that $M$ is an oriented rational homology sphere such that $\pi_1 (M)$ requires 2 generators. If $\pi_2 (M) \neq 0$, then $M$ contains an embedded $S^2$ which is nontrivial in homotopy (by the sphere theorem). This sphere must be two-sided, and so by cutting $M$ along the sphere, you write $M$ in a nontrivial way as the connected sum of two manifolds; and both of them are rational homology spheres, and none is simply connected (by the Poincare conjecture). By Grushko's theorem, the fundamental groups of both pieces are cyclic.

Comment: If I am not mistaken (!), this shows, together with the poincare conjecture, that $M$ is a connected sum of two lens spaces. So unless $M$ is a sum of lens spaces, it has $\pi_2 (M) =0$.

Comment: A nice collection of examples comes from double branched covers $S^3$ branched along a 3-bridge knot.  These all have Heegaard genus 2, and hence their fundamental group is generated by at most 2 elements. Moreover, the double branched cover of a knot is always a rational homology sphere.  3-manifolds with Heegaard genus 2 are always branched covers over the 3-sphere with branch set a knot or link.

Comment: An interesting sidelight to this question is that a 3-manifold whose fundamental group is generated by 2 elements may have Heegaard genus greater than 2. Examples that are Seifert fibered spaces are due to Boileau-Zieschang (Invent. Math. 76 (1984), no. 3, 455–468), and more recently Tao Li (J. Amer. Math. Soc. 26 (2013), no. 3, 777–829) found hyperbolic examples.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented and answered for their help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the greatest class of rank 2 3-manifolds (including rational homology spheres) are the genus 2 manifolds, which as indicated by Ruberman are double branched covers over links (coming from the hyperelliptic involution of the genus 2 surface which extends over both handlebodies). This includes connect sums of lens spaces and all the spherical space forms, as you indicated. However, it was a celebrated result of [Boileau and Zieschang](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01388469) that there are certain Seifert-fibered spaces with rank 2 fundamental group, but Heegaard genus $=3$. They completely classified the rank 2 Seifert fibered spaces. These examples were extended by [Weidmann](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-003-4742-9) and [Schultens-Weidmann](https://doi.org/10.2140/pjm.2007.231.481)  to certain graph manifolds (with rank $2$ fundamental group and genus $>2$). I think the state of the art in the non-hyperbolic case is a partial classification theorem of [Boileau-Weidmann](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.top.2004.10.008).

It is still unknown whether 2-generated hyperbolic 3-manifolds have Heegaard genus 2. Thurston observed that such manifolds are also branched covers over a link in $S^3$. Also, certain finiteness results are known for hyperbolic manifolds with rank 2 fundamental group, genus $>2$, and injectivity radius bounded below which has been [written by Souto](https://msp.org/gtm/2007/12/p015.xhtml) (see also [Biringer-Souto](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/jdq106) for the higher rank case).

Comment: The link following the text "These examples were extended by Weidmann" actually goes to a paper by by Boileau and Zieschang. (I have edited mainly to replace the dead link to Souto's paper - but since I have noticed this too, I left at least a comment.)